# Split arbitrary number of special characters in regex and give the array size

Tags: java, regex

I have s string in which * can come at arbitrary number. The regex pattern I use doesnt split at the beginning. I do not want to do the String.substring() to remove the * in the beginning. It can be that I have something like `"***place1*place2**place3*"`. Or something like `placeStr=**`

```
 String placeStr="*place1*place2**place3*";
 String[] places=placeStr.split("(\\*)+");
 System.out.println("array size" + places.length);
```

Also while using `String.split("(\\*)+")`to remove the `placeStr=**` gives a wrong array size if the input string is something like `***`. In this case I get array size as one. But I expect array size to be zero, since there is no places inside the array. What I want to count is the number of places.

Comment: I suppose you do not want to have an empty item in the array. Use matching code then with `[^*]+` regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to deal with empty strings while doing split in case there are multiple stars in the beginning, just replace the stars in beginning and then just do a simple split.

Sample code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String placeStr = "***place1*place2**place3*";
    placeStr = placeStr.replaceAll("^[*]+", "");
    String[] places = placeStr.split("[*]+");
    System.out.println("places.length: " + places.length);
    Arrays.asList(places).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Prints,

```
places.length: 3
place1
place2
place3
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted to do.

**Editing answer to clarify about split:**

Considering your code,

```
String placeStr="*place1*place2**place3*";
String[] places=placeStr.split("(\\*)+");
System.out.println("array size: " + places.length);
```

You will get,

```
array size: 4
```

because the first star in the string splits and gives empty string. But if you remove all the stars in the beginning of string and make your code like this,

```
String placeStr="place1*place2**place3*";
String[] places=placeStr.split("(\\*)+");
System.out.println("array size: " + places.length);
```

Then this will output array size as,

```
array size: 3
```

The last star(s) (or any char) characters in the string does not behave like the first characters, and upon splitting, they don't give empty string in the last array elements.

This is how splitting a string by a regex works in java. Let me know if you had some other expectation, may be due to which you are saying it is giving you wrong output.

Hope this clarifies.

Also, can you let me know what you want to achieve logically?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I was little not sure if this is what OP wanted, and you may be right, OP doesn't want to split from any star in the beginning or end. Updated regex to take care of that and now there will be no empty line in the beginning as split will happen only in the intermediate stars.

Comment: Looking at the question, OP might also want to use `s.replaceFirst("^\\*+", "").split("\\*+")`.

Comment: I think a simpler thing would be to first remove all the stars in the beginning and end of regex and then just do a simple split on `[*]+`

Comment: You do not need to remove them at the end, `split` discards all empty items at the end. `|[*]+$` is unnecessary complication.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes you are right. the last stars don't need to be dealt with. You've got tremendous experience Wiktor.

Comment: @Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi The length of the array is wrong. Please see the newly added sentence in the question

Comment: @learningUser: The length of array is not wrong because I have removed all the stars in the beginning due to which the string that is split reduces to `place1*place2**place3*` which if split with [*]+ will give you length 3 only. It is not very clear from your post as to what you really want to do. I thought you wanted to get rid of extra empty line that appeared when you split when there were multiple stars in the beginning of string. Can you please clearly mention in your post, what do you expect vs what is actually happening?

Comment: @Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi  hopefully i made it more clear in the question now

Comment: @learningUser: You are adding the samples but not actual vs expected output. Let me modify my answer to give some clarifications which may help you.